# Warning about <noscript> tag for gist when run jekyll server

Tags: jekyll, noscript, gist

I embeded a gist using `{% gist octocat/0831f3fbd83ac4d46451 git-author-rewrite.sh %}`, then I ran `jekyll server`, came this warning:

> Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2015-08-28 19:43:12
>   Warning: The  tag for your gist octocat/0831f3fbd83ac4d46451
>   could not be generated. This will affect users who do not have JavaScript available or enabled in their browsers.
>   Warning: The  tag for your gist octocat/0831f3fbd83ac4d46451 could not be generated. This will affect users who do not have JavaScript available or enabled in their browsers. ...done in 7.157032 seconds.

And the page generated looked strange: extra word displayed. Reason unknown.
Gem jekyll-gist has been installed already. What can I do with this? I googled for several hours, but with no luck.

Edit: Hmm, add pictures to show why this question came out:

- noscript tag warning:

[image]

- extra word 'true' displayed:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a github repository ?

Comment: Yes, I have one. But, this gist is just from others. I thought I should use the present gist instead of cloning new one.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this bug. Can you push your actual code in a _test_ branch ?

Comment: What? I can't catch you. I'm sorry! I'm just writing a new post and want to embed this gist, then comes this problem. I suggest you to clone my only repo: https://github.com/kenmux/kenmux.github.io, and just create a new post using gist. Then you can get what you want. :)  ps: my jekyll version is: v2.5.3.

Comment: That's what I've done. With `{% gist octocat/0831f3fbd83ac4d46451 %}` but no warning. What can be interesting is to see code that generate your error.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue from time to time. I don't know why... Wait! One thing came into my mind! What will happen when running this behind some corp proxy? My pc ran with error(it cannot connect to github at all), and mbp with warning(but it can get repo from github normally). I'll try this at home later.

Comment: Yes, it's the issue related with proxy. I also can't reproduce at home without proxy. But I've no idea **what actually goes wrong**. Even nobody ran into it before?

Comment: In order to paste gist code in the noscript tag, jekyll-gist made a request to https://gist.githubusercontent.com/octocat/0831f3fbd83ac4d46451/raw . Failing attenpt to get code result in the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close this issue, let me add something.
Yes, this is related with proxy, and the jekyll (my version is 2.5.3). In my case, I ran `jekyll server` just behind the http proxy, and jekyll threw out a warning, generated this html code (I thought there may be something wrong):

```
<p>true<script src="https://gist.github.com/octocat/0831f3fbd83ac4d46451.js?file=git-author-rewrite.sh"></script></p>
```

So you can see the extra word 'true'.

To avoid this, I just insert the script instead of embedded gist (retrieved from the generated code):

```
<p><script src="https://gist.github.com/octocat/0831f3fbd83ac4d46451.js"></script></p>
```

I recommend the audiences to use script instead of gist. There's another reason: if you want to run jekyll and overview site offline, the embedded gist will cause a connection error.